# Process of melody line to orchestral music

Tags: piano, composition, orchestration

I have a one-note melody song, like a simple folk song. I want to arrange a somewhat simple orchestral piece out of it.

I do play piano and I'll be able to change it to a somewhat interesting piano piece which will be a good first step. I want to make a orchestral piece out of it but I don't really know what a good process/workflow will be to be able to do this.

Are there any systems/workflows/process you can advise to do this?

Comment: If you haven't already, search for this topic elsewhere on the site. There are a variety of questions about the process of orchestration. The [orchestration] and [arranging] tags would be good places to start.

Comment: Orchestrating from never having orchestrated before might be an overly long and complicated answer for a site like this. There’s a lot of art to it. If you’ve listened to and studied a lot of orchestral works already then I think imitating the orchestrations you like most or fit the melody best makes sense. If you haven’t, then it’s going to be essentially impossible to take you from zero to full orchestra in a single SE answer. If you know how to write four-part harmonies that would be helpful also.

Comment: So much depends on what you already know. I suggest one way to get more insight into orchestration without spending any money is to look for a free PDF of a book on orchestration written by Nikolai Rimsky-Korsakov. It’s public domain now. If that book seems over your head then you probably have some background material to learn, like more about the instruments of the orchestra and/or music theory.